# Linked list doesn't work

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following code, when I add nodes why does it reset all nodes to the most recent nodes data? Assuming everything else in the codes works correctly, parsing etc. can anyone identify a problem with the list. See output at the bottom.

```
typedef char* string;
typedef struct linked_list listType;
typedef struct linked_list* linked_list;
typedef struct node NodeType;
typedef struct node* Node;

typedef enum boolean{
    true = 1,
    false = 0
}boolean; 

struct node{
    Node next;//next node in the list
    string *transData;//listAdd--->string data[]
};

struct linked_list{
    Node head;//first node in the list
    int size;//size of list, number of nodes in list
};

boolean add(linked_list list, string *data)
{
    boolean retval = false;//default retval is false
    Node nod;//node to add
    nod = (Node)malloc(sizeof(NodeType));
    nod->transData = data;
    nod->next = NULL;

    //list size is 0
    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = nod;
        printf("First Node added: '%s'\n", nod->transData[0]);fflush(stdout); 
        retval = true;
    }

    //nodes already in list
    else
    {
        printf("List with nodes already\n");
        fflush(stdout); 
        Node node = list->head;

        //iterating through nodes
        while(node->next != NULL)
        {
            node = node->next;
        }//while

        node->next = nod;
        printf("Node added: '%s'\n", nod->transData[0]); fflush(stdout);
        retval = true;
    }

    list->size+=1;
    return retval;//success
}

/**
 * Returns the size of the list.
 */
int listSize(linked_list list)
{
    return list->size;
}

/**
 *Can only print with 2 or more elements
 */
void printList(linked_list list)
{
    int i=0;
    Node nod = list->head;
    int length = listSize(list);
    printf("ListSize:%d\n",listSize(list));
    fflush(stdout);

    while(nod->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("Node %d's data: %s\n", i, nod->transData[0]);
        fflush(stdout);
        nod = nod->next;
        i++;
    }
}//printlist
```

Output:

```
trans 5 5  
Argument 1: trans  
Argument 2: 5  
Argument 3: 5  
Last spot(4) is: (null)  
name of command: trans  
ID 1  
First Node added: 'trans'  
ListSize:1
>>check 4  
Argument 1: check  
Argument 2: 4  
Last spot(3) is: (null)  
name of command: check  
ID 2  
List with nodes already  
Node added: 'check'  
ListSize:2  
Node 0's data: check  
>>trans 4 4  
Argument 1: trans  
Argument 2: 4  
Argument 3: 4  
Last spot(4) is: (null)  
name of command: trans  
ID 3  
List with nodes already  
Node added: 'trans'  
ListSize:3  
Node 0's data: trans  
Node 1's data: trans  
>>check 5  
Argument 1: check  
Argument 2: 5  
Last spot(3) is: (null)  
name of command: check  
ID 4  
List with nodes already  
Node added: 'check'  
ListSize:4  
Node 0's data: check  
Node 1's data: check  
Node 2's data: check
```

Comment: Post the code where you add nodes to the list

Comment: linkedList buffer = newList();//.......  
boolean bool;  
printf("ID %d\n", id);  
fflush(stdout);  
id++;  
bool = add(buffer, arrOfInputCommands);//..........

Answer (score 3):

(The OP tells me that the nodes need to have arrays of strings, so the pointer-to-a-pointer thing is actually correct).

Anyhow, it looks like your problem is that every node has a pointer to the same buffer. You just keep copying different strings into the same buffer, and then you assign the address of a pointer to that buffer to each new node.

First, I'd get rid of those typedefs. I don't know how much clarity they're really adding.

Next, you need to allocate new storage for each string. The standard library strdup() function is a handy way to do that:

```
//  Turns out it's a fixed-size array, so we can blow off some memory 
//  management complexity. 
#define CMDARRAYSIZE 21

struct node {
    Node next;
    char * transData[ CMDARRAYSIZE ];
};

//  Node initialization:

int i = 0;

struct node * nod = (struct node *)malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
//  Initialize alloc'd memory to all zeroes. This sets the next pointer 
//  to NULL, and all the char *'s as well. 
memset( nod, 0, sizeof( struct node ) );

for ( i = 0; i < CMDARRAYSIZE; ++i ) {
    if ( NULL != data[ i ] ) {
        nod->transData[ i ] = strdup( data[ i ] );
    }
}
```

...but then be sure that when you free each node, you call free( nod->transData[n] ) for every non-NULL string pointer in nod->transData. C is not a labor-saving language.

Comment: in my node struct I need to store an array of strings, or char*

Comment: OK, that complicates things: You'll have to dynamically allocate a sufficiently large array of string pointers (with malloc()), and then dynamically allocate the strings themselves. The key issue is still the fact that each node needs its own storage for its own information, and in C, that means dynamically allocating it with malloc()/calloc()/realloc() (or in the special case of strings, strdup()).

Comment: add(buffer, arrOfInputCommands);  
    and I know that char *arrOfInputCommands[21];  
    then could I say: nod->transData = (char **)malloc( sizeof( char * ) *21);??

Comment: You'd be a lot better off with "#define INPUTCOMMANDARRAYSIZE 21" somewhere at the top of the file. Actually, if it's definitely a fixed size, you could save some effort and define it as "char * transData[INPUTCOMMANDARRAYSIZE];" -- you can do that in a struct, if it's a fixed-size array. You'd definitely want to be zeroing the whole mess with "memset( nod, 0, sizeof( struct node ) );"

Comment: Do that, and you don't have to bother allocating or freeing transData -- just free each of the non-null char *'s in it, and free the whole struct.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is probably due to pointer copying. You are likely referencing the same buffer in all your nodes. Try to make a copy of your string data with `strdup` for example.

Comment: I am storing an array of strings(char** whatever) in my transData.. that won't work with strdup()..

Answer (score 1):

Not the main issue, but your `printList` won't print out the last element.

Instead of `while(nod->next != NULL)`  use `while(nod != NULL)`